# How do I create an image of a webpage and save the image to my server using .net?

Tags: asp.net

I have a page that dynamically generates a small html page containing 1 small table w/text.  I want to be able to take a picture (png preferable) of that page and save it to my server.

I was previously using a 3rd party solution (ABCdrawHTML2), but I have changed servers and this one does not have it.  Is there a way to do it without 3rd party solutions?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it using the Windows.Forms WebBrowser:

```
public class WebSiteThumbnailImage
{
    string m_Url;
    int m_BrowserWidth, m_BrowserHeight, m_ThumbnailWidth, m_ThumbnailHeight;
    Bitmap m_Bitmap = null;

    public WebSiteThumbnailImage(string url, int browserWidth, int browserHeight, int thumbnailWidth, int thumbnailHeight)
    {
        m_Url = url;
        m_BrowserWidth = browserWidth;
        m_BrowserHeight = browserHeight;
        m_ThumbnailWidth = thumbnailWidth;
        m_ThumbnailHeight = thumbnailHeight;
    }

    public Bitmap GenerateWebSiteThumbnailImage()
    {
        Thread m_thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(_GenerateWebSiteThumbnailImage));
        m_thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        m_thread.Start();
        m_thread.Join();
        return m_Bitmap;
    }

    private void _GenerateWebSiteThumbnailImage()
    {
        WebBrowser m_WebBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        m_WebBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;           
        m_WebBrowser.Navigate(m_Url);
        m_WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted);

        while (m_WebBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)          
            Application.DoEvents();

        m_WebBrowser.Dispose(); 
    }

    private void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {            
        WebBrowser m_WebBrowser = (WebBrowser)sender;
        m_WebBrowser.ClientSize = new Size(this.m_BrowserWidth, this.m_BrowserHeight);
        m_WebBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        m_Bitmap = new Bitmap(m_WebBrowser.Bounds.Width, m_WebBrowser.Bounds.Height);
        m_WebBrowser.BringToFront();
        m_WebBrowser.DrawToBitmap(m_Bitmap, m_WebBrowser.Bounds);
        m_Bitmap = (Bitmap)m_Bitmap.GetThumbnailImage(m_ThumbnailWidth, m_ThumbnailHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

To use this, at the appropriate place in your code-behind, do something like:

```
WebSiteThumbnailImage thumbnail = new WebSiteThumbnailImage(url, 1000, 1000, 200, 200);
Bitmap image = thumbnail.GenerateWebSiteThumbnailImage();
image.Save(filePath);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however I am very new to asp.net and have no idea how to implement this.  Is this like a function?  How do I add in the url to grab or the location to save?  Sorry for not knowing what I am doing, but I am trying to learn a lot quickly.  I've been using php for the last 5 years.

Comment: This is a class for you to use in your aspx.cs code behind. Wherever you need to create the thumbnail, create an instance of this class and then call the GenerateWebSiteThumbnailImage function. It will pass you a bitmap back for you to save in whatever format you wish.

Comment: @AmazingChase sorry, forgot to ping.

Comment: "This is a class for you to use in your aspx.cs code behind." How do I do this exactly?  I'm sorry for the repeat question.  I understand what this does (it seems perfect), but I am completely lost as to how to call it.

Comment: When I put that code into my aspx page I get this compilation error: public keyword is not vaild as an identifier.  I just don't understand the syntax of .net pages apparently.

Comment: I read a couple tutorials and it seems that I needed to create a aspx.cs and reference it as codebehind, which I have done.  I copied the website thumbnail class to it.  On my aspx page however I still can not come up with how to call it.  I just need to supply the html location and the save path, which I have done:  WebSiteThumbnailImage thumbnail = new WebSiteThumbnailImage(table_html, 195, 538, 180, 535);
 Bitmap image = thumbnail.GenerateWebSiteThumbnailImage();
 image.Save(Server.MapPath("temp_files/"+user_name+"_student_chart_filled_top_image.bmp"));   I'm missing something still.

Comment: @AmazingChase Ok, create a class in visual studio. Right click your project (new item->new Class). Call it WebSiteThumbnailImage. Copy the code above into the class. In your codebehind, in the page load or a button click or wherever you want to generate the image. Call the second piece of code I posted above. I would highly recommend you take the time to learn C# before going any further. The APress C# pro is an excellent book.